# How to get a text from HTML using Watir?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir (watir-webdriver) with Ruby to write an automated testing script.

I am trying to get the text which is random numbers, in this case `103QUL6M`, from the HTML. Since the random number text is different every time I run the script, I want to make sure my code works every time. After I get the  text I want to store it in a variable.

```
<div id="folio-main">
    <div id="main">
    <form action="/servlets/ProcessAction?identifier=orderConfirmationForm" method="post" name="orderConfirmationForm">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="info">
    <div id="OrderDetails" class="detailsLT">
    <h3>Order Details</h3>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"> Order Number: </td>
    <td class="tdData">**103QUL6M**</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <ul class="listLinkCol">
        <ul class="listLinkCol">
        <ul class="listLinkCol">
        </div>
        <div id="OrderHelp" class="detailsRT">
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <p>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy Peasy.

```
$browser.div(:id => "OrderDetails").table(:index => 0).rows[0].cells[1].text
```